# Handling database objects in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In general how does javascript interpret a `Database {}` object? I am writing some back end scripts to handle a registration form verification. In particular I need to ensure that the username and email used to register is not currently in use. To do this I use the sqlite3 package and use a few `db.get` calls to determine if there are existing entries in my database for the username and email used on the registration form. I want to use the return of `db.get` to check if it is empty or not and use this conditional to perform the necessary task. However the `db.get` returns a `Database {}` object which I am unfamiliar of how to work with.

Hopefully the following pseudo describes the issue better. Here `uname` returns `Database {}` and so never fails the if statement.

```
function existance(username, email) {
    
    let uname = db.get(sql, username, callback(err, throw));
    
    if (uname) {
        let errors = {username: 'Username already in use.'};
        return errors;
    }
    
};
```

**EDIT**

I have since used Gajiu's recommendation but still having issues. So I have two files:

**registrant_existence.js**

```js
// necessary requirements and initialisation

function registrant_existence(username) {

    let uname;
    let sql = 'SELECT username FROM table WHERE username=?';
    
    db.get(sql, username, function(err, row) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        uname = row;
        console.log(uname);
    }
    });
    
    console.log(uname);
    
    if (uname !== undefined) {
        return {username: 'Username already in use.'};
    } else {
        return 'DNE';
    }
    
};

module.exports = registrant_existence;
```

**register.js**

```js
let registrant_existence = require("path to registrant_existence.js");

// necessary requirements and initialisation

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    
    let existence = registrant_existence(req.body.username, req.body.email);
    
    if (existence != 'DNE') {
        // render registration page notifying the user
        // that the username is already in use
    } else {
        // register the new user details
    }
    
});
```

The `uname` variable is undefined always. I placed the `console.log(uname)` in two spots in registrant_existence.js as is seen above to see what is happening. Two strange things occur.

The first is that the `console.log(uname)` *outside* the `db.get()` displays `undefined` in the console and the `console.log(uname)` *inside* the `db.get()` displays the expected string (a username I know is in my database).

The second is that the `console.log(uname)` *outside* the `db.get()` is displayed before the `console.log(uname)` _inside the `db.get()` in my console.

I have no idea why these things are happening. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like that:

```
db.get(sql, username, (err, data) => {
    // process the data here 
    if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  return data
    ? console.log(data.id, data.userName)
    : console.log('No username found');
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. I want to embed the `db.get()` into another function and so I will need the "outer" function to return if `db.get()` returns a non-empty entry. What you've proposed will only return the callback function inside `db.get()` and not my "outer" function.

Comment: Actually I realised I was being silly. Your solution works. I just defined the variable outside `db.get` and update it using the callback function.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared I'm happy it worked for you, please accept my answer it helped you

Comment: Actually it did not work. I keep getting a result which is undefined even though I know the database has a matching entry. The main post will be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a wrapper around your Database object, something like an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), this one is used regularly https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html

On the other hand for your specific use case you might want to get a look at this https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#unique_constraints: unicity is usually via constraints in the data store.